# php htaccess multiple extensions

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, web, html-helper

Ok for example i want: youtube.com/channel.php?c=pinch
to be : youtube.com/channel/pinch

i have tried the code,but i dont know how to add an extension to an extension.. (channel/pinch), it stays as ex. youtube.com/channel?c=Pinch...

```
#Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

Could somebody fix the code and add to the code so i have the extension? Thanks!